# Declaring a string array in the UI thread then populating it from the background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Hello I am currently developing an android bank app project.

I have two threads the UI and the bankThread running as the background thread to do all the necessary bank operations.

In this activity I am using string arrays to inflate a listview so the user can view transactions made on their account.

I have declared these string arrays in the Ui thread and then used the handler from the bank thread to populate them however after I have done this these arrays all return null and the app crashes due to a null pointer exception.

I've used Localbroadcastmanager to send these string arrays as a broadcast in another class and its worked perfectly, yet in this class the string arrays still remain null.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

The code:

```
public class ViewTransactionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView transactionsListView;
public static volatile String[] tranDates;
static volatile String[] tranTypes;
static volatile String[] tranDescs;
static volatile String[] tranAmounts;
BankThread bankThread;
Context mContext;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_transactions);
    bankThread = MainActivity.getBankThread();
    transactionsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.transaction_list_view);
    final TextView errorTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_transactions_error_text);


    bankThread.handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tranDates = bank.getAccTranDate();
            tranTypes = bank.getAccTranTypes();
            tranAmounts = bank.getAccTranAmount();
            tranDescs = bank.getAccTranDesc();

            Intent tranArraysIntent = new Intent("getTransactionInfo");
            tranArraysIntent.putExtra("theTypes", tranTypes);
            tranArraysIntent.putExtra("theDates", tranDates);
            tranArraysIntent.putExtra("theAmounts", tranAmounts);
            tranArraysIntent.putExtra("theDesc", tranDescs);
            if (tranAmounts != null || tranDates != null || tranDescs != null || tranTypes != null)
                errorTextView.setText("Alls grand.");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(tranArraysIntent);

        }
    });

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("getTransactionInfo"));


    if(tranAmounts != null || tranDates != null || tranDescs != null || tranTypes != null) {
        TransactionAdapter transactionAdapter = new TransactionAdapter(this, tranTypes, tranAmounts, tranDescs, tranDates);
        transactionsListView.setAdapter(transactionAdapter);
        errorTextView.setText("Complete.");
    }else{
        errorTextView.setText("A boo-boo has occurred.");
    }

}

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        tranTypes = intent.getStringArrayExtra("theTypes");
        tranAmounts = intent.getStringArrayExtra("theAmounts");
        tranDates = intent.getStringArrayExtra("theDates");
        tranDescs = intent.getStringArrayExtra("theDesc");

    }
};

}
```

Here's the error stack trace:

```
02-18 21:35:44.198 28081-28081/com.example.mk.bankapptest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mk.bankapptest, PID: 28081
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mk.bankapptest/com.example.mk.bankapptest.ViewTransactionsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
    at com.example.mk.bankapptest.ViewTransactionsActivity.onCreate(ViewTransactionsActivity.java:56)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Hi! Can you share with us the "NullPointerException" stacktrace? Thanks!

Comment: Sure! I'll ad it now - Cheers!

Comment: what is actually `bank` object and where did you initialize it?

Comment: The bank object is initialised and run on the background thread called bankThread which is started on the onCreate method of the MainActivity. The bank object basically does everything a back would do such as creating accounts, getting account information, withdrawals etc. I can post the code for class if that helps get the bottom of it. Kinda new to android so I'm teaching myself basically all of it so I'm not sure if I'm actually doing it the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
  errorTextView.setText(tranDates[0]);
```

At this moment, `tranDates` is null.

You should put this line in your Runnable (or directly remove the line).

Regards

Comment: Thank you  for the reply. I was using that  line to see if it was null I should probably remove it from my question. Is there anyway I can get it to equal the bank.getAccTranDates() outside the runnable instance or keep the values its gets assigned in it ?  so I can use that string array in a layout inflater??